# Bluetooth on Windows 10 suddenly stopped working

Tags: windows-10, bluetooth

A few days ago I wanted to use my computer's Bluetooth function, but the option to turn it on/off wasn't there. I ran the troubleshooter which, after updating the drivers, fixed the problem. Recently I've been using Bluetooth without any problems, but this morning it stopped working. The on/off option is gone again. Running the troubleshooter only gives this message:

"Bluetooth is not available on this device. Please try using an external adapter to add  Bluetooth capability to the computer."

I know Bluetooth is available, as I was using it yesterday. I've tried updating the drivers again, but without any success. Anyone know what the problem might be?

Comment: Look in Device Manager and see if the Bluetooth hardware is there or not there if the hardware has failed.

Answer (score 1):

I've had that happen on my work computer.

Besides updating drivers, system firmware, and the OS, the issue persisted and the Bluetooth device would come and go.

I had the computer repaired under warranty and that resolved the issue and it has not reoccured.

So, you can check for drivers and BIOS updates and OS updates, and if that doesn't resolve the issue, you have a hardware problem that needs to be fixed as appropriate.

Answer (score -1):

If blue tooth module is not correctly loaded in the BIOS this can happen.
Before going for hardware repair try to Hard Reset the system.

I have edited the answer in response to the comments of music2myyear. So instead of hard press the button when the system is on, hard press when it is off. If it is a desk top remove the CMOS Battery for a minute.

1. Perform a hard shut-down by holding the shift key is held down whilst selecting Windows Shut Down
2. Ensure your computer is unplugged
3. Hold down the power key for 93 seconds. That's 90, which is the maximum recommended elsewhere plus 3 to make sure it is over 90!
4. Press the power key briefly to start your computer
5. Allow it to start fully.

6). Check whether the blue tooth button is back.

Comment: On any Windows computer in the past 20 years that doesn't "hard reset" the computer. It just hard shuts down the computer, potentially damaging system software that has not had time to unload properly. If you wish to "reset" a laptop, you could turn the computer off the normal way and hold the power button down for 60 seconds or so. On a desktop you'd disconnect power and remove the CMOS battery for a minute or so.